# Handle HTTP Error via REST

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I'm trying to customize an endpoint in javascript that is reachable by a REST call. This endpoint handles several conditions, related to different cases (basically it generates a one time password and then validate it checking if it is expired or not... etc).

So basically the structure is like this:

```
(function() {
    var obj = new Object();
    ...
    if (...) {      
       obj.code = 422;      
       obj.message = "Code Expired";        
       return obj;
    } else {...}
    ....
    if (...) {          
       obj.code = 423;      
       obj.message = "No more attempts";        
       return obj;    
} else {...} 
})();
```

I set up an object at the start and then map a json message in order to retrieve a body with different code/message response.
So when the endpoint enters these conditions it returns the object and the Header is always a 200 (the call is successful). Something like this:

> HTTP/1.1 **200** OK "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN", "cache-control":
>   "no-cache", "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
>
> ### "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "date": "Thu, 01 Jun 2017 15:17:44 GMT"
>
> {
>       "code": 422,
>       "message": "Code Expired" 
>   }

Is it possible to map the in the status code the error? In order to retrieve something like:

> HTTP/1.1 **422** Unprocessable Entity "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN", "cache-control":
>   "no-cache", "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
>
> ### "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "date": "Thu, 01 Jun 2017 15:17:44 GMT"
>
> {
>       "code": 422,
>       "message": "Code Expired" 
>   }

Comment: So you want to copy some data from the response body into the response status code. Where do you want to do this? On the client or on the server? What HTTP library are you using?

Comment: These endpoint are related to an application called OpenIDM, I'm not sure which kind of library they are using

Comment: You just need to get `response.status` code to place in your `if` blocks. How to do it depends on your environement. Ary you using any frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just needed to throw an error code in the return, something like

```
...
else {
  throw {
    code : 400,
    message : "Error"
  };
}
...
```